# Wordpress - SESSION variable does not last

Tags: php, wordpress

I've spent some time researching answers on this problem, but neither have resulted in fixing my issue. I attempted to make use of the $_SESSION variable. On the first page, I put the result of a input form entry (a name) into it, as it will be used across a variable number of pages. On the page after, the session variable seems to be working fine. I used a var_dump to debug it and everything seems to be set well. Then I click the link I created to go to the next page in this chain of linking. I assume that because the session is being saved, the variable will last until the user exits the website or browser.

Suddenly, on this second page, the session variable becomes null again.

I did a temporary fix where I just pass the GET value from the first page and plug it into the link page links url through some php. It works as intended, but will love to be able to make sessions work when I get to more complicated problems.

Comment: so check the session ID on each page. if it's changing and you're NOT using session_regenerate_id, then you've got a configuration error and are ending up with a brand new empty session on this "next page".

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of all your pages?

Comment: I have session_start, yes. I'll do a session ID check and get back to you on the results.

Comment: Yes, the session ids are all the same, even on the page where the session variable zaps.